# XSLT Recursive function (Parent - child relationship)

Tags: xml, xslt

I have trouble finding a solution for the following problem:

I need to give a property with the XSLT that is equal to a:CrsNr.
Now it has to find the right node where the input property matches a:CrsNr.
After the right node is found it needs to print all the definitions from the upper levels from high to low seperated by **::**.

The nodes are linked by Code and ParentCode

PS: There are also other nodes between the nodes I need. This is just a simple example, the full xml counts +- 33.000 lines.

I'll give you a XML and output example

**XML**

```
<root xmlns:a="urn:xa" xmlns:i="urn:xi">
    <a:OrganisatieEenheid>
      <a:Code>00000001</a:Code>
      <a:Level>0</a:Level>
      <a:Definition>Antwerpen</a:Definition>
      <a:CrsNr>7001</a:CrsNr>
      <a:ParentCode i:nil="true"/>
    </a:OrganisatieEenheid>
    <a:OrganisatieEenheid>
      <a:Code>00000004</a:Code>
      <a:Level>1</a:Level>
      <a:Definition>Zorgbedrijf</a:Definition>
      <a:CrsNr>7004</a:CrsNr>
      <a:ParentCode>00000001</a:ParentCode>
    </a:OrganisatieEenheid>
    <a:OrganisatieEenheid>
      <a:Code>00000426</a:Code>
      <a:Level>2</a:Level>
      <a:Definition>Raad van Beheer</a:Definition>
      <a:CrsNr>7426</a:CrsNr>
      <a:ParentCode>00000004</a:ParentCode>
    </a:OrganisatieEenheid>
</root>
```

**output**

```
<output>
   <Definition>Antwerpen::Zorgbedrijf::Raad van Beheer</Definition>
   <InputCrs>7426</InputCrs>
</output>
```

Comment: The namespaces in your input XML are not bound. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (and that's a big if), you want something like :

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:a="urn:xa"
xmlns:i="urn:xi"
exclude-result-prefixes="a i">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="crs" select="7426"/>

<xsl:key name="org-by-crs" match="a:OrganisatieEenheid" use="a:CrsNr" />
<xsl:key name="org-by-code" match="a:OrganisatieEenheid" use="a:Code" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <Definition>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('org-by-crs', $crs)"/>
        </Definition>
        <InputCrs><xsl:value-of select="$crs"/></InputCrs>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:OrganisatieEenheid">
    <xsl:if test="a:ParentCode[not(@i:nil='true')]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('org-by-code', a:ParentCode)"/>
        <xsl:text>::</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="a:Definition"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is applied to a **well-formed input**:

```
<root xmlns:a="urn:xa" xmlns:i="urn:xi">
    <a:OrganisatieEenheid>
      <a:Code>00000001</a:Code>
      <a:Level>0</a:Level>
      <a:Definition>Antwerpen</a:Definition>
      <a:CrsNr>7001</a:CrsNr>
      <a:ParentCode i:nil="true"/>
    </a:OrganisatieEenheid>
    <a:OrganisatieEenheid>
      <a:Code>00000004</a:Code>
      <a:Level>1</a:Level>
      <a:Definition>Zorgbedrijf</a:Definition>
      <a:CrsNr>7004</a:CrsNr>
      <a:ParentCode>00000001</a:ParentCode>
    </a:OrganisatieEenheid>
    <a:OrganisatieEenheid>
      <a:Code>00000426</a:Code>
      <a:Level>2</a:Level>
      <a:Definition>Raad van Beheer</a:Definition>
      <a:CrsNr>7426</a:CrsNr>
      <a:ParentCode>00000004</a:ParentCode>
    </a:OrganisatieEenheid>
</root>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<output>
   <Definition>Antwerpen::Zorgbedrijf::Raad van Beheer</Definition>
   <InputCrs>7426</InputCrs>
</output>
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast respons michael.hor257k! This is the answer to my question. I just had todo some fine tuning (Because this was an xml example) but that just fine! Thank you very much for helping me out with this. I'm new in this whole XML/XSLT story and it is really confusing for me to work with templates. Thanks again, great job!

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps,
Well you can't have properties but you can have params that represent external data sent to the xslt.

I have assumed that the value has been sent via param

```
    <xsl:param name="data"/>
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <output>
      <Definition>
        <xsl:variable name="found" select="a:OrganisatieEenheid[following-sibling::a:OrganisatieEenheid[a:CrsNr=$data]]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="data2">
          <xsl:for-each select="$found">
            <xsl:value-of select="a:Definition"/>
              <xsl:text>::</xsl:text>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="data3" select="a:OrganisatieEenheid[a:CrsNr=$data]/a:Definition"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($data2,$data3)"/>
      </Definition>
      <InputCrs>
        <xsl:value-of select="$data"/>
      </InputCrs>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your stylesheet is incomplete, you have merely posted one template. I cannot test it even when I try to fit your template in a standard stylesheet element - because you did not say how you rendered the OP's input XML well-formed.

Comment: Sorry Mathias Muller. I had assumed that the xml posted erroneous by mistake and hence rectified it while developing the template. I am still new to this forum hence I am asking should I have asked Domi to post the rectified xml.!!

Comment: I'm sorry for the XML. Thanks for your respons to help me with this problem!